# CSS + jQuery toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am working on a menu using jQuery + CSS3.

I have an up arrow on the right side of the menu and when clicked the menu slides up and the image switches to a down arrow.

The only problem is that if you click the down arrow, it does't slide back down, even though I've provided a somewhat legit piece of code in order for it to work.

I am new to jquery so any help would be very much appreciated!

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="tfc-new-nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.html">Shopping Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">My Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-menu menu-active"></div>
</nav>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#tfc-new-nav {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #808E91;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

#tfc-new-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#tfc-new-nav ul li {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
}

#tfc-new-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Felix Titling', serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: background .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background .3s ease-in;
    transition: background .3s ease-in;
}

#tfc-new-nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #50798D;
}

#tfc-new-nav .hide-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#tfc-new-nav .hide-menu.menu-active {
    display: block;
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Black_Up_Arrow.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
}

#tfc-new-nav .hide-menu.menu-hidden {
    display: block;
    background-image: url('http://www.wpclipart.com/signs_symbol/BW/direction_arrows/down_arrow.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
}​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tfc-new-nav .hide-menu.menu-active").click(function() {

        $("#tfc-new-nav").animate({

            top: "30px"

        });

        $(this).removeClass("menu-active");
        $(this).addClass("menu-hidden");

        $(this).animate({
            top: "35px"
        });

    });

    $("#tfc-new-nav .hide-menu.menu-hidden").click(function() {

        $("#tfc-new-nav").animate({

            top: "95px"

        });

        $(this).removeClass("menu-hidden");
        $(this).addClass("menu-active");

        $(this).animate({
            top: "20px"
        });

    });

});​
```

## [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ModernDesigner/Fma52/4/)

Comment: I actually have a header above the menu which the menu will slide under, but that's not included in the fiddle, just on the actual page. But that should give you an idea.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to include the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .live() instead .click()

Example:

```
$("#tfc-new-nav .hide-menu.menu-hidden").live("click", function() {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

This takes into account updated manipulation of the DOM, tested and worked

Comment: @ModernDesigner It is - [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) - *As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().*

Comment: Huh. That's weird because I'm using the latest version of jQuery (on my site, not the fiddle) using `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Just because some method is marked as deprecated doesn't mean it won't work. It means you should stop using it because it won't be update and will be removed on a upcoming version.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for the understanding. Like I said, I'm still a bit new to jQuery. So what I did was use `.on()` instead of `.click()` and for future readers I'll see if I can still edit the answer. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should delegate your events, like

```
$("#tfc-new-nav").on("click", ".menu-hidden", function() {
    ...
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fma52/6/)

Comment: I was wondering if they would change live as it doesn't make sense, though the new selector for .on() seems pretty pointless unless it has speed improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `$.slideToggle()` to handle this and minify your code.

Here is a link to the manual entry: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

This will animate and set `display:none` when the anitmation is complete.

Comment: No, `$.slideToggle()` won't work because the menu slides under the header but the bottom part is still visible, that way the user can still click the down arrow to reveal the menu again. I didn't include the header in the jsFiddle (didn't think it was necessary).